# In PMWiki: Header logo link formatting

Tags: header, skin, pmwiki

Any PMWiki folks here? I am using the [Skittlish skin](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Skins/Skittlish) which has a header logo. When I declare the logo in local/config.php it displays logo PLUS the $WikiTitle. Here is the header code:

```
! %block sitetitle%[[{$ScriptUrl} | {$WikiTitle} ]]
(:div class="sitetag":){$WikiTag}
(:divend:)
```

I have tried editing config.php to change the wiki title to nothing '' - doesn't work. 
I have tried removing the {$WikiTitle} directive in the header code - doesn't work.

any help would be great. I'm a noob at PMWiki.

thanks,
J

Comment: do you have the $WikiTag variable set? Do you have more than one SiteHeader page? IE, Is the above extract from Site.SiteHeader or a {group}.SiteHeader page? Are any of your changes to that extract reflected on the site?

Comment: Hey Michael. Fixed by setting the $WikiTag variable to a hard space &nbsp;  thanks-J

Answer (score 1):

Discovered that setting the $WikiTag variable to a hard space: "& n b s p;" resolved the issue.